# Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 101 to 100

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am attempting to build a weather app as part of a Flutter course I am taking, and a message stating:

> Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 101 to 100

appears in my console, when I would expect weather data instead. Is anyone familiar with this message?

I am pasting the code from the screens involved below, for reference.

**location_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants.dart';

class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LocationScreen({this.locationWeather});
  final locationWeather;
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.locationWeather);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/location_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_city,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '32°',
                      style: kTempTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '☀️',
                      style: kConditionTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  "It's  time in San Francisco!",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: kMessageTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
/*

double temperature = decodedData['main']['temp'];
int condition = decodedData['weather'][0]['id'];
String cityName = decodedData['name'];
*/
```

**loading_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:clima/screens/location_screen.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/networking.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/networking.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'location_screen.dart';

const apiKey = 'APIKEY';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoadingScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

  void getLocationData() async {
    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();
    latitude = location.latitude;
    longitude = location.longitude;
    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$apiKey');
    var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return LocationScreen(
            locationWeather: weatherData,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitDoubleBounce(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 100.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**networking.dart**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper(this.url);

  final String url;

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      return jsonDecode(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should disconnect your app. Delete it from the device or emulator if you're using one, then cold restart your app again. It will work just fine.
It worked for me on my device.